# How can I drag group (g) element in D3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to make a draggable `<g>` element containing a `<circle>` and a `<text>` but I failed.

Now I have this code:

```js
var margin = {top: -5, right: -5, bottom: -5, left: -5},
    width = 1960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 1500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
    .origin(function(d) { return d; })
    .on("dragstart", dragstarted)
    .on("drag", dragged)
    .on("dragend", dragended);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);


var dotContainer = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "dotContainer")
    .datum({x:220, y:120})
    .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; })
    .call(drag);

var dot = dotContainer.append("circle")
    .attr("class", "dot")
    .datum({x:220, y:120})
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
    .attr("r", 5).call(drag);

var text =  dotContainer.append("text")
    .datum({x:220, y:120})
    .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; })
    .text('Title');  



function dragstarted(d) {
  d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
  d3.select(this).classed("dragging", true);
}

function dragged(d) {
  d3.select(this).attr("cx", d.x = d3.event.x).attr("cy", d.y = d3.event.y);
}

function dragended(d) {
  d3.select(this).classed("dragging", false);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

`<circle>` element is perfectly draggable, ok. But I need to apply dragging to the whole `<g>` element to drag my circle together with the `<text>` element.

How can I do this?

When I apply `call(drag)` to `dotContainer` like this

```
dotContainer.call(drag);
```

then nothing works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should rewrite your `dotContainer` variable this way:

```
var dotContainer = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "dotContainer")
    .datum({x:220, y:120})
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return 'translate(' + d.x + ' '+ d.y + ')'; })
    .call(drag);
```

Remove `.call(drag)` for `dot` variable and rewrite `dragged` function like this:

```
function dragged(d) {
  d.x += d3.event.dx;
  d.y += d3.event.dy;

  d3.select(this).attr("transform", function(d,i){
    return "translate(" + [ d.x,d.y ] + ")"
  });
}
```

Thus we use `transform` attribute for an initial container position and for the position update during the dragging.

Check demo in the hidden snippet:

```js
var margin = {top: -5, right: -5, bottom: -5, left: -5},
    width = 1960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 1500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
    .origin(function(d) { return d; })
    .on("dragstart", dragstarted)
    .on("drag", dragged)
    .on("dragend", dragended);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);


var dotContainer = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "dotContainer")
    .datum({x:20, y:20})
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return 'translate(' + d.x + ' '+ d.y + ')'; })
    .call(drag);

var dot = dotContainer.append("circle")
    .attr("class", "dot")
    .datum({x:20, y:20})
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
    .attr("r", 5)

var text =  dotContainer.append("text")
    .datum({x:20, y:20})
    .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; })
    .text('Title');  

function dragstarted(d) {
  d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
  d3.select(this).classed("dragging", true);
}

function dragged(d) {
  d.x += d3.event.dx;
  d.y += d3.event.dy;
            
  d3.select(this).attr("transform", function(d,i){
    return "translate(" + [ d.x,d.y ] + ")"
  });
}

function dragended(d) {
  d3.select(this).classed("dragging", false);
}
```

```css
.dotContainer {
  cursor: move;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```